# What is meant by the tuple notation in Linear Algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

I am taking a course in linear algebra.  A question on an assignment is as follows:

> Let $A$ and $B$ be $n\times n$ real matrices.  Show that if $(x,Ay) = (x,By)$ for all x and y in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $A=B$.

I am quite confused as to the notation of

> $(x,Ay) = (x,By)$

This would appear to me to be two tuples, but the question doesn't make a lot of sense if that is the case, for one this statement would be *trivially* equivalent to

$$Ay = By$$

And the variable $x$ would be entirely useless.  After this reduction the remainder of the proof would still be rather trivial as $\forall y \in \mathbb{R}^n : Ay = By$ is essentially the definition of equality.

I couldn't think of anything else that this notation might represent and I truly doubt that a question this simple would be asked, so I tried to do some searching both on math.se, the duck duck go and of course my notes for the course.

What does this notation mean?

---

<sup>I don't know if anyone intends to do this, but I would really appreciate if no one mentioned the solution or suggested any methods for solving the problem.  I would like to solve this myself and would consider this to ruin the problem.</sup>

Comment: $(x,y)$ most likely means the inner product of $x$ and $y$ in this case.

Comment: Scalar product or inner product.

Comment: @carmichael561 I do think that is unlikely as both in other places on the assignment and in my notes inner product has been represented by $\langle x, y \rangle$

Comment: I can't think of anything else it could be. You should ask your instructor.

Comment: @carmichael561 Inner product does seem to make sense.  I will ask, thank you.

Comment: @EpsilonNeighborhoodWatch It might be that the notation changed during the assignment (maybe due to carelessness or due to copying the question from a source that uses a parentheses instead of angle brackets). Given the context of your question, it is almost certainly the same inner product. If you are still skeptical, ask your instructor.

Comment: Perhaps the instructor was confused by $(x,y)=2\langle x,y\rangle/\langle y,y\rangle$...